# pyspark collect_list with groupby and row_number issue: order of rows changes each time I call show()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, row-number

Is the behavior listed below expected or it is a bug??

## Create a DF

```python
data_list = [
    ['Blue', 2, 3, 1],
    ['Green', 1, 5, 4],
    ['Green', 4, 1, 3],
    ['Blue', 2, 4, 1],
    ['Green', 1, 5, 2]
]
all_cols = ['COLOR','COL1','COL2','COL3']
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data_list, all_cols)
df.show()
+-----+----+----+----+
|COLOR|COL1|COL2|COL3|
+-----+----+----+----+
| Blue|   2|   3|   1|
|Green|   1|   5|   4|
|Green|   4|   1|   3|
| Blue|   2|   4|   1|
|Green|   1|   5|   2|
+-----+----+----+----+
```

## Add a ROW_ID

```python
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
df = spark.sql('select row_number() over (order by "COLOR") as ROW_ID, * from df')
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- ROW_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- COLOR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COL1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- COL2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- COL3: long (nullable = true)
df.show()
+------+-----+----+----+----+
|ROW_ID|COLOR|COL1|COL2|COL3|
+------+-----+----+----+----+
|     1|Green|   4|   1|   3|
|     2| Blue|   2|   4|   1|
|     3|Green|   1|   5|   2|
|     4| Blue|   2|   3|   1|
|     5|Green|   1|   5|   4|
+------+-----+----+----+----+
```

## Create another DF by applying 'groupby' on the 1st one:

```python
grp_df = df.groupby(col_grp_by).agg(collect_list('ROW_ID').alias('IDX_VAL'))
grp_df.show()
+-----+---------+
|COLOR|  IDX_VAL|
+-----+---------+
|Green|[1, 3, 5]|
| Blue|   [2, 4]|
+-----+---------+
grp_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- COLOR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IDX_VAL: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

## See below if I execute 'grp_df.show()' again.

## The list elements within the 'IDX_VAL column have changed!!!

```python
grp_df.show()
+-----+---------+
|COLOR|  IDX_VAL|
+-----+---------+
|Green|[2, 3, 5]|
| Blue|   [1, 4]|
+-----+---------+
```

Comment: If I keep listing the elements of the dataframe the contents of the lists within the 'IDX_VAL' column keep changing!!! grp_df.show()
18/07/22 16:31:53
+-----+---------+
|COLOR|     R_ID|
+-----+---------+
|Green|[2, 3, 5]|
| Blue|   [1, 4]|
+-----+---------+


grp_df.show()
18/07/22 16:32:00 
+-----+---------+
|COLOR|     R_ID|
+-----+---------+
|Green|[2, 3, 5]|
| Blue|   [1, 4]|
+-----+---------+


grp_df.show()
18/07/22 16:32:07
+-----+---------+
|COLOR|     R_ID|
+-----+---------+
|Green|[1, 3, 5]|
| Blue|   [2, 4]|
+-----+---------+

Comment: Don't post code in the comments - it's very hard to read. Instead [edit] your question and add the new information.

Comment: The first worrisome thing is that you specified `order by "COLOR"` but the `ROW_ID` is clearly *not* ordered by color. In fact you'll see that the weird behavior is actually in `df` (try `df.show()` a few times and compare that with `df.sort('COLOR').show()`) - that it shows up in `grp_df` is actually a side-effect.

Comment: Thank you pault! How can I 'stabilize' the grp_df DF in order to have no side-effects from the original DF?? I must say that I do need a 'ROW_ID' index to be created in the original DF df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469014/pyspark-collect-list-with-groupby-and-row-id-issue/51482004#comment89931729_51469014), the issue in the grouped dataframe is actually a side effect of the original dataframe being ordered seemingly by random. Notice how in your example, `ROW_ID` does not order the DataFrame by `COLOR` even though that's what you specified it to do, *or was it*?

The problem is that you have quotes around `"COLOR"` in `order by "COLOR"`. This makes it the string `"COLOR"` and not the column `COLOR`.

Consider the difference in execution plans:

```python
spark.sql('select row_number() over (order by "COLOR") as ROW_ID, * from df').explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Project [ROW_ID#350, COLOR#326, COL1#327L, COL2#328L, COL3#329L]
#+- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(COLOR ASC NULLS FIRST, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS ROW_ID#350], [COLOR ASC NULLS FIRST]
#   +- *Sort [COLOR ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
#      +- Exchange SinglePartition
#         +- Scan ExistingRDD[COLOR#326,COL1#327L,COL2#328L,COL3#329L]

spark.sql('select row_number() over (order by COLOR) as ROW_ID, * from df').explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Project [ROW_ID#342, COLOR#326, COL1#327L, COL2#328L, COL3#329L]
#+- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(COLOR#326 ASC NULLS FIRST, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS ROW_ID#342], [COLOR#326 ASC NULLS FIRST]
#   +- *Sort [COLOR#326 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
#      +- Exchange SinglePartition
#         +- Scan ExistingRDD[COLOR#326,COL1#327L,COL2#328L,COL3#329L]
```

You can see the second one (correct) has `COLOR#326` in the Window spec definition- this shows that it's using the column for the order.

So if you remove the quotes, you should see more consistent results:

```python
df = spark.sql('select row_number() over (order by COLOR) as ROW_ID, * from df')
df.show()
#+------+-----+----+----+----+
#|ROW_ID|COLOR|COL1|COL2|COL3|
#+------+-----+----+----+----+
#|     1| Blue|   2|   3|   1|
#|     2| Blue|   2|   4|   1|
#|     3|Green|   1|   5|   4|
#|     4|Green|   4|   1|   3|
#|     5|Green|   1|   5|   2|
#+------+-----+----+----+----+
```

Notice that the DataFrame is actually sorted by `COLOR`.

```python
grp_df = df.groupby('COLOR').agg(f.collect_list('ROW_ID').alias('IDX_VAL'))
grp_df.show()
#+-----+---------+
#|COLOR|  IDX_VAL|
#+-----+---------+
#| Blue|   [1, 2]|
#|Green|[3, 4, 5]|
#+-----+---------+
```

However, you may still get inconsistent ordering within the same `COLOR` because you did not specify how to break ties after ordering by `COLOR`. This won't impact the grouped values in this specific case, but it's recommended that you ensure that the ordering is deterministic in all cases.

For your data, you can achieve deterministic results by doing:

```python
df = spark.sql(
    'select row_number() over (order by COLOR, COL1, COL2, COL3) as ROW_ID, * from df'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

row_number( ) is known to function in non-deterministic manner when it encounter ties in assigning the order.It can potentially assign different row number every time you call out action on pyspark. If you want to keep it immutable and if the order is immaterial to you except for the column "COLOR", use cache or persist.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
df = spark.sql('select row_number() over (order by "COLOR") as ROW_ID, * from df')
df.persist()

grp_df = df.groupby('COLOR').agg(F.collect_list('ROW_ID').alias('IDX_VAL'))
grp_df.show()
+-----+---------+
|COLOR|  IDX_VAL|
+-----+---------+
|Green|[1, 2, 3]|
| Blue|   [4, 5]|
+-----+---------+

grp_df.show()
+-----+---------+
|COLOR|  IDX_VAL|
+-----+---------+
|Green|[1, 2, 3]|
| Blue|   [4, 5]|
+-----+---------+
```

Additionally, as others have pointed out, it is best to break the tie by specifying other criteria for order.